# Is it possible to call a function while not using all of its code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a JS function that returns a value but has an `alert` command in it. I want to assign the returned value to a variable later on in the code. Is there a way to call the function but to ignore the `alert` command, in order to just assign the returned value to a variable later?
For example:
Let's say I have`function f1(num) {  alert ("hi);  return num * 2; }`
and then`function f2() { var x = f1(2); return x;}`.
How can I ignore the `alert` and only save the returned
value in a variable on later functions?

Comment: no clue what you are asking. Sounds like if you want to bypass something, you need to add a parameter to bypass it.

Comment: I can give you a code example: Let's say I have 'function f1(num) { alert ("hi);  return num * 2;} ' and then 'function f2() { var x = f1(2); return x;}. When I run 'f2()', the 'alert' command will be performed. How can I avoid this 'alert' and only save the returned value?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include your previous attempts as [Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with a succinct explanation of where those attempts didn't meet your requirements (including any pertinent error messages, expected vs. actual behaviors, etc.).

Comment: See how much more clear it is when you post code... put the code in your question.

Comment: This is going to sound facetious, but the essence of programming is a) code that does stuff and b) controlling the flow so that some executes and some doesn't. (I know, that wasn't really helpful.) If you don't want the alert at all you can just remove it. If you want the `alert` only `if` some condition is true then you could write an `if` statement. `if(something){alert("whatever");}

Comment: Thank you. I am a little expirienced in programming so I am familiar with `if` conditions, but the example I gave is just an abstraction. I want to use it for something a bit more complex, as the function that plays the role of `f1()` is performed in an `onclick` event. Is there a way for me to check if the function is called in an `onclick` event or not? If so, I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional parameter to `f1()` to skip the `alert`:

```js
function f1(num, skipAlert) {
  if (skipAlert !== true) alert("hi");
  return num * 2;
}

function f2() {
  var x = f1(2);
  return x;
}

function f2_skipAlert() {
  var x = f1(2, true);
  return x
}

document.querySelector('button#alert').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(f2());
});

document.querySelector('button#skip-alert').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(f2_skipAlert());
});
```

```html
<button id="alert">Run with alert</button>
<button id="skip-alert">Run without alert</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Solution if you cannot change the `f1` function

You can disable it with the following. Remember to define the disable function before the execution of the one that contains the `alert` function.

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

If you need to re-enable it, you can do temporarily associate it to another variable:

```
var oldalert = window.alert;
```

Then disable it as I did before and then re-enable later with `window.alert = oldalert;`

> As esqew said, it's not a good practice to override it

**Example of Use**

```
function disableAlert(){
  window.oldalert = window.alert;
  window.alert = function() {};
}

function enableAlert(){
  window.alert = window.oldalert;
}
```

And then, in your `f2` function you can do like this:

```
function f2() {
  disableAlert(); 
  var x = f1(2);
  enableAlert(); 
  return x;
}
```

### Solution if you can change the `f1` function

Similar to esqew solution but using default parameters

```
function f1(num, skipAlert = false) {
  if (skipAlert) alert("hi");
  return num * 2;
}

function f2(skipAlert = false) {
  var x = f1(2, skipAlert);
  return x
}
```

If you want to call with `alert` you can use `f2(true)` otherwise just `f2()`.

Comment: I would be wary of overriding a blocking function like `alert()`, as some legacy libraries rely on the functionality of its blocking nature for various things. Also seems to be a bit overkill for the OP's use case.

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly should I place these commands? And should I copy-paste exactly what you've written? If I look on the code example I've shown in the question, where do these fit and how exactly will they be written?

Comment: esqew is right, so try to avoid this kind of stuff. Anyway, I just updated the reply.

Comment: Thank you, I will try.